# When to use Process.EnterDebugMode

Tags: c#, debugging, process

On the MSDN page about [Process.EnterDebugMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enterdebugmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it says:

> Some operating system processes run in a special mode. Attempting to
>   read properties of or attach to these processes is not possible unless
>   you have called EnterDebugMode on the component.

What is the **special mode** that is referred to here?

Comment: It you ever iterated the array returned by Process.GetProcesses() and displayed info about each process then you'll know what this is talking about.  Try it.

Comment: What info.  I have indeed done this - and just re-done it in response to your comment, but none the wiser I am afraid.  Could you give an example of a "special" process, and why it is special, how to know what processes are in this "special" category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "special mode" is simply adding [SeDebugPrivilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx#SE_DEBUG_NAME). As [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) points out, [If you grant somebody SeDebugPrivilege, you gave away the farm](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/14/8080140.aspx).

A user with SeDebugPrivilege can connect to any process and debug it. When you debug a process you can inject code into it. So from a security point of view, the user is basically an administrator.